# Automatically map network drives for every user that logs into Mac

Tags: macos, applescript, plist

*EDIT*

Thanks to Simon White I now have this working. Turned out it needed to be saved as a scpt file instead of an app. I have amended the code below to show this:

I am a total beginner to AppleScript and launchctl so please bear with me.

I want every user who logs into a Mac to run something to mount 5 network volumes and change the Finder Preferences to show connected servers and hard disks on the desktop. So far I have created the following AppleScript to do this, and it works if dragged into the user's login items. I have saved this as 'netvols.app' to the /Applications folder.

```
-- Mount network drives
tell application "Finder"
    try
        mount volume "smb://path/to/share"
        mount volume "smb://path/to/share"
        mount volume "smb://path/to/share"
        mount volume "smb://path/to/share"
        mount volume "smb://path/to/share"
    end try

    -- tell Finder preferences to show hard disks and connected servers on the desktop
    tell Finder preferences
        set desktop shows hard disks to true
        set desktop shows connected servers to true
    end tell
end tell
```

It works when in the user's login items and when run manually, but I cannot get it to work for every user that logs into the machine. I have tried adding it to /Library/StartupItems but that does not work.

Most recently I have tried adding a plist file to /Library/LaunchAgents but it does not work- in the console I can see the error:

```
launchctl: launchctl: no plist was returned for: /Library/LaunchAgents/login.plist
```

Below is my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>IglooLogin</key>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        <string>/Applications/Mount Network Volumes.scpt</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have changed the owner and permissions of the file with the below:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchAgents/login.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchAgents/login.plist
```

If I try to run the plist manually with launchctl in the terminal using:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/login.plist
```

I get the following error:

```
launchctl: no plist was returned for: /Library/LaunchAgents/login.plist
launchctl: no plist was returned for: /Library/LaunchAgents/login.plist
nothing found to load
```

I'm sure there is something extremely simple that I'm missing, but as I've mentioned this is completely new to me so please be gentle :)

*EDIT*

Right so I discovered a fairly obvious syntax error in my plist file- D'OH!

Anyway now I have encountered an entirely new error-

```
com.apple.launchd: (IglooLogin[1072]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13
```

As far I understand, 13 is a permissions error but I still am no closer to figuring out why!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Something to consider is you can add the network disks to each user’s login items if you need them to be mounted at login. Then set the Finder preferences manually just once. That may be an appropriate solution for you.

How is the app failing when you run it from another user account? Do you see any error message? Is the app running and then quitting and the disks aren’t mounting?

I don’t think what you’re doing with the plist is the answer. Keep in mind, when you save an AppleScript as an app, it is no longer an AppleScript, it is a Mac app. It has its own plist inside its package. The user has to launch it as an app. Your troubleshooting steps should probably be similar to what you’d do if you installed any Mac app and other users could not run it successfully. For example, you might try changing the settings in the Security & Privacy pane of System Preferences so that apps from unidentified developers are allowed. (Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere.)

You should test for the values of the preference settings before setting them, otherwise you will be setting them again and again to true, even if they are already true.

Change these lines:

```
tell Finder preferences
        set desktop shows hard disks to true
        set desktop shows connected servers to true
end tell
```

… to this:

```
tell Finder preferences
    if desktop shows hard disks is equal to false then
        set desktop shows hard disks to true
    end if
    if desktop shows connected servers is equal to false then
        set desktop shows connected servers to true
    end if
end tell
```

And you’re not specifying a username in your “mount volume” lines. As long as that is what you mean to do, that is fine.

You can name your app “Mount Network Disks” to make it easier for people other than yourself to identify and use later. There is no requirement for a Mac app to have a short name like that. The requirement is for obviousness and ease of use. Even if a user is just looking in their login items and they see “Mount Network Disks” instead of “netvols” that is helpful to that user.

Comment: Thank you for the response it's very helpful. The reason I didn't want to have to add it to the user's login items is because there may be domain users logging into the Mac that aren't set up and I would like them to connect automatically to the servers.

Comment: The app fails with the same error in other accounts that log into the Mac. I have managed to get this working now! I have amended the question to show the correct code.